# Get last row index for a specific number in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column consisting of single numbers and blank spaces. The numbers are not unique, but can occur in multiple cells. I want to find the row index for the last number 9 (i.e., in the photo above it is in row 12). What formula can I use for this purpose? I cant get it to work with MATCH or INDEX.

[image: example image of the column of numbers and empty spaces]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) which lets you search on a column a specific key (in your case `C1`, to return the last value `1/(A:A=C1)` is used) and returns a specific range of matches (in your case to return the row index the formula takes use of [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)):

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(1,1/(A:A=C1),ROW(A:A)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(ROW(A1:A),A1:A=9),COUNTIF(A1:A,9))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=INDEX(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A=9)),)
```

Comment: I think that's the simplest one!